# Mouth detection in Opencv detects multiple areas in android

Tags: java, android, opencv, opencv3.0, face-detection

I am new to android. I am using opencv to detect face and mouth of a person. It is not detecting mouth correctly. Can you help me in this?
Here is my code:

```
mJavaDetectorLip = 
loadClassifier(R.raw.haarcascade_mcs_mouth,"haarcascade_mcs_mouth.xml", 
cascadeDir);
......
 Rect liparea = new Rect(new Point(20,20),new Point(mGray.width() - 20, 
  mGray.height() - 20 ));
 lipArea(mJavaLip,liparea,100);
  ......
```

here is my code:

```
   private Mat lipArea(CascadeClassifier clasificator, Rect area, int 
    size) {
    Mat template = new Mat();
    Mat mROI = mGray.submat(area);
    MatOfRect mouths = new MatOfRect();
    Point lips = new Point();

    //isolate the eyes first
    clasificator.detectMultiScale(mROI, mouths, 1.1, 2, Objdetect.CASCADE_FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT
            | Objdetect.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE, new Size(30, 30), new Size());

   Rect[] mouthArray = mouths.toArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < mouthArray.length;) {
        Rect e = mouthArray[i];
       e.x = area.x + e.x;
        e.y = area.y + e.y;
        Point center1 = new Point(e.x  + mouthArray[i].width * 0.5,
               e.y + mouthArray[i].height * 0.5);
        int radius = (int) Math.round(mouthArray[i].width / 2);
        Imgproc.circle(mRgba, center1, radius, new Scalar(255, 0, 0), 4, 8, 0);

new Scalar(0,255,0),1,8,0);

        return template;
    }

    return template;
}
```

It is not staying in one place, it is moving around the whole face.

Answer (score 1):

> It is not staying in one place, it is moving around the whole face.

It is an expected behavior as the features of mouth are very much limited and there is a high chance of false positives. For example your eyes would also have similar features as your lip. To mitigate this issue, [OpenCV docs](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_objdetect/py_face_detection/py_face_detection.html#haar-cascade-detection-in-opencv) suggest that we must first detect the faces in a given frame, if there are multiple then choose a single one depending upon area of face rect or some other param. After successful detection of face, divide the face rect into halves and search for the lips in the lower half only.

This would significantly increase your accuracy, because the Haar features for face are pretty complex and well trained. Narrowing down your search domain from the whole frame to lower half of your face would save time as well.

Comment: It is working in landscape mode only. When I move to portrait mode, it detects lips somewhere on shoulders.

Comment: I guess it is some other issue please debug the frames passed for feature detection and also make sure that you are rendering the lips with correct logic. Try debugging deeper into the variables it shall work in both landscape and portrait mode.